# How to get the id from json file and display in view laravel for translations

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-localization

I want to get the id from my messages.php file e.g:
`"apple": "Apple is..", "pear": "Pear is..."`

and display it in my view dynamically, getting the page's id from my json file.
For example I want to do something like this, but it won't work:
`{{ __('messages.'{{$fruit_data->id}}')}}`

Keep in mind that in json and messages.php file the id's are the same exactly.

Comment: that looks very wrong, shouldn't it be something more along the lines of 
``{{ __('messages.'.$fruit_data->id) }}``

Comment: you will need to convert your json back to array, try json_decode

Comment: @MysticSeagull you are the best man!